# Registered Application Has Failed

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy

I'm trying so hard to submit my app to Samsung Galaxy Watch store, but it seems impossible. Every attempt I get a compatibility error. Is there a way to correct submit the app to the store?

Pls find below the error log that I got.

**Issue Type**

> Ad-Hoc

**Title**

> Unable to download application through GALAXY Apps

**Description**

> Unable to find the app due to the minimum supported OS version of Gear
>   application.
>   - Min OS version which app defined : 5.0
>   - Latest OS version of Gear Tizen 4.0 Bezelless:4.0.0.6
>
> 1. Connect a Gear to a mobile device using Gear Manager
> 2. Check minimum supported OS version of Gear application and OS version of Gear device
> 3. Try to find the app -> Unable to find the app
>
> App just should be served for devices that have
>   compatible OS  Detected Device: SM-G975F_SM-R825U,
>   SW Version: R825USQU1ASHH_G975FXXU3ASH6

**Detected Device Group**

> Gear Tizen 4.0 Bezelless-Premium Galaxy (fHD WQHD)

Comment: That log looks like your app requires OS version 5.0, but the latest available is 4.0?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using wrong `required_version` for your app. To fix that, go to your `config.xml` and change `required_version` to `4.0` or lower. And also make sure that you are not using any `Tizen 5.0` specific api which are not supported in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple task actually. In the config.xml file I just changed to version 4.0. I don't know why there's a 5.0 version if none of the gears support it.

[image]